# npm publish module includes iOS framework. When npm install of that module, the iOS framework is corrupt

Tags: ios, frameworks, npm, ios-frameworks

This is the strangest issue and only happens on one iOS framework in particular (that i noticed) within an npm module.

when clicking on the framework (before npm publish) I see:

```
frameworkname.framework
|
- Headers (dir)
- frameworkname
- Versions (dir)
    |
    -A (dir)
    -Current (dir)
```

I published this module to a private npm server.  When I install the npm module the framework is corrupt.  I see:

```
frameworkname.framework
|
- Headers (dir) MISSING
- frameworkname MISSING
- Versions (dir)
    |
    -A (dir)
    -Current (dir) MISSING
```

After reading http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios it looks like the missing files are symlinks.  Has anyone else seen this behavior before?  How do I keep the symlinks from being lost during the npm process?

Comment: Hi ideluca, I ran into problem recently. I found your question while searching stack overflow and was wondering if you had found an answer.

Comment: There is a discussion of this issue with a suggested workaround (but no solution at present) on the npm issues tracker on Github: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7825

Comment: Also see the Cordova issues tracker: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6092

Answer (score 1):

The missing files are symbolic links, and unfortunately, npm doesn't support symbolic links. As a workaround, you can replace the links with their targets (and remove the targets to prevent duplication).

E.g. for a framework FFF with the structure:

```
./FFF -> Versions/Current/FFF
./Headers -> Versions/Current/Headers
./Versions
./Versions/A
./Versions/A/FFF
./Versions/A/Headers
./Versions/Current -> A
```

you can run the following (in bash) from inside the framework directory:

```
framework=FFF && rm $framework Headers && mv Versions/A/{$framework,Headers} . && rm -rf Versions
```

to change the structure to:

```
./FFF
./Headers
```